# Why does this code only loop 4 times?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

Background: I am trying to clarify the mystery of pointers and dynamic memory allocation in C. I am trying to get several floating point inputs from user, store them in an array that is allocated dynamically and thus expanded to accommodate more values. Once the user enters 0, the loop terminates and the sum and average are calculated and printed. I am using Borland C 5.02

Problems: 
1. The loop only works 4 times and then the 4th value is not stored!
2. If I replace x+i with x[i] and *(x+i-1) with x[i-1] I get "Floating point error: Stack Fault" "Abnormal Program termination.

```
int main(void)
{
   float *x;
   float sum=0;
   float avg=0;
   int i=0;

   x=(float*)malloc(sizeof(float));

   do
   {
        scanf("%f",x+i);  //take input

      i++;
      x=(float*)realloc(x, i*sizeof(float));  //reallocate memory to store more values
      if(x==NULL){printf("WARNING");}

      printf("\n%f    %p   %d\n",*(x+i-1),x,i);

   }while(*(x+i-1)!=0);

   for(int j=0;j<i;j++)
   {sum=sum+*(x+j);} // Sum all values

   avg=sum/(i-1);   //Find result, i is 1 bigger than number of values, ith value is 0

   printf("\n\n%d   sum: %f   avg: %f ",i,sum,avg);
   getch();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's been a long time, so my C is hazy.  Does pointer math work that way?  The x+i part?  I'd have thought it'd have just incremented the address by that value, not by the value * sizeof( object ).  Try maybe x[ i ] instead?

Comment: Don't cast the return value of malloc

Comment: `x+i` is equivalent to `(char *)x + sizeof(float) * i`.  In other words, yes, pointer math does work that way.  By definition, `x[i]` is exactly the same as `*(x + i)`.

Comment: Casting the return value of `malloc()` is not necessary in C, but is harmless.  In C++ you do need to do a cast, or else you get an error.

Comment: You can try replacing `(x + i)` with `&x[i]`, which should work.  But if you use `x[i]` then you are trying to pass a float value where you need a pointer.

Comment: quantum231, @Turix has given you the solution.  Please don't forget to "accept" his answer and give him the credit.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since `i` is 0-based, your realloc should be:
`x=(float*)realloc(x, (i+1)*sizeof(float));`

Comment: Nice spot there. Didnt catch that at first.

Comment: But he increments `i` prior to `realloc()` so his code isn't wrong.

Comment: MY GOSH, to think the problem was so simple I am SHOCKED.

Comment: Ah!  Light dawns!  He does increment `i` prior to `realloc()` but the `+1` is still needed.  On the first loop, `i` starts at 0.  Then one number is entered.  Then `i` is incremented to 1.  But a `realloc()` using `i * sizeof(float)` will only make room for a single float!  It needs a `+1` to make the extra room for a new float yet to come.

Comment: Now I will do the remaining questions from chapter 7 of the book. Thanks.

Comment: Is counting really that difficult? The initial malloc is for one float. The next malloc is for 0+1 floats. BTW, less prone to such errors is to get rid of that initial malloc, set x=NULL, and realloc at the head of the loop.

Comment: Yes. If counting weren't difficult for most people, software would be a damn lot safer... :)

Comment: Actually I thought I need to malloc before I can use realloc. So I can use realloc without having malloced before. I see

Answer (score 0):

I compiled your program and ran it.  I built with `-g` and tried debugging it.  It gives this message and then a stack backtrace:

```
*** glibc detected *** ./a.out: realloc(): invalid next size: 0x0000000000797010 ***
```

For me, it dies after the 6th number.

I did a search on the above error message about "invalid next size" and haven't found anything really useful.  All the answers I found are basically "you did something that corrupted your heap" but in your program I don't spot anything that should be doing that.

EDIT: Okay, sure enough, it was heap corruption caused by writing after the end of the allocated memory.  That should teach me.  There was one call to `realloc()` and one place that was writing to the memory; the bug had to be one of those two lines!

Comment: I got it, its what Turix pointed out. MY GOSH, to think the problem was so simple I am SHOCKED. I wonder why the program works correctly for a few times and than crashes in the wrong version rather than not run at all.

Comment: That is the way heap corruption bugs work!  You write in the wrong place, and seemingly nothing happens... then later you get a crash that has seemingly no connection with the actual problem.

Comment: I am impressed. I have done C programming and C# and VHDL and Matlab and HTML but I haven't tried to dig deep into C/C++ pointers. I thought well I just have to do it and so the story begins. Now I understand why the code I wrote for the Programmable Audio Router Mixer last year to run on the PIC seemed to work ok for a while but than crash strangely.